# Highlight specific lines in Jenkins Email-Notification using Pre-send Script

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins-email-ext

I would like to highlight few lines in Jenkins email-notifications using Pre-send script. I am new to Jenkins but so far I have created job which sends me email-notification with text from log file as email body.

I would like to use regex for deciding which lines to highlight and then highlight these lines in red color. So can I use Python in pre-send script?

Can you please give me pointers on how to do this?

I configure log file to show in email body using `Content Type` set to HTML and  `Default Content` set to following text,

`<pre>
${FILE,path="market_activity.out"}
</pre>`

Comment: It would be a groovy script.